# Change Snowflake WH Size before Run in Informatica

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, iics

When running an Informatica IICS job into Snowflake, the batch warehouse is sized for the biggest jobs. Is there a way within Informatica to alter the warehouse size so that we can run with a smaller WH for most of the jobs but then scale it up when we run just the big jobs? This would allow us to better size the batch warehouse but then scale it automatically when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just use a pre SQL command to resize the warehouse before the task/job runs